# Multiple Entities, Multivariate, Multi-step - Time Series Prediction - Python

Tags: python, time-series

**My goal is to create a time series model with**

1. **Multiple Entities** - I have multiple products with pre orders and they all have the a similar bell shaped curve peeking at the release date of the product but different orders of magnitude in unit salles OR I can use their cumulative slaes what is an "S" shaped curve. But I  only have about 100 products 1 year of daily data to do the training on.
2. **Multivariate** - I have a wide variety of data on these indie movies for each day: A.) number of times people added them to the Wishlist, B.) page views, C.) time spent on the page AVG, -> Y.) Target value is the number of products people payed for (it is the same pre order before release and normal purchase after release date)
3. **Multi-step** - predicting 60 days ahead would be the goal
4. Every day refreshing the predictions for every product - Does this requires me to retrain the modell on the whole dataset?

**Already Read**

- I have found algorithms that can do prediction on 1 variate maybe even Multivariate. Multi-step is already problematic and I don't know how to add the Multiple Entities part at all. So I cant fine a project or guide that would contain all these 3 parts that I nd
- I have tried LSTM (13 different models with different datasets) but on longer "Multi-step" it is not working so more than 1 or 2 days. I also cant make the LSTM to accept Multiple Entities so I just chained each products data after each other historically, I do understand that it is not an optimal practice for sure.
- Python package non popular so I cant find projects to it - https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/412355/256200
- I always see this R guide but I don't use R. I need help with Python - https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html
- Not multiple variable and not Multi-step - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356008/multiple-time-series-prediction-python

Comment: Have you tried XGBoost? It seems difficult at first view to predict 60 days with only 365 days of training, but it could be possible with some data pre processing. I had to deal with similar problems but with stock markets, and I had to find the right time range sampling (ex: grouping the mean values for one week) to make better predictions.

Comment: I have used XGBOOST before for Regression and Classification. I am not sure how to push the target value historically back to predict the future. I am not sure about his whole turning time series problem to regression problem. I would love to see a guide on it.

Comment: I've found this code but I don't know if it could be helpful or not: https://programmersought.com/article/96993038054/